# Track and throttle downloads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, download

If I have a rails application that allows for file uploads and downloads, how can I programatically throttle the speed at which a person can download a file?

I can set it in nginx like this:

```
limit_rate 150k;
```

but how should should I do this within rails, programatically, so the `send_file` method sends its file at a slower speed depending on how much they've already downloaded?

How should I track how much they've downloaded?

Tell me if you think this is a good idea:

1. Give `File` model a `size` attribute
2. When user requests a file, log the file's `size` to an encrypted cookie
3. For subsequent downloads, keep on adding each file's `size` to the integer in the cookie
4. Set up a before hook that checks if the encrypted cookie's number is under `x` number of bytes. If it's greater than `x`, begin throttling via the first part of this question. Bigger than `y` redirect to captcha, ect...

**I'm open to seeing how to overcome this problem redirecting to nginx...**

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't throttle downloads in Rails - you'd be tying up a whole Rails instance for longer. In fact, I wouldn't use Ruby to serve files at all if possible.

I would set up the webserver to serve files directly, then redirect to those. I'm sure with some cleverness you could set up different configurations in nginx for different virtual directories, for example, then programatically choose them by using different download links...